# I set values for pixels by setRGB but after saving image getRGB gets different values, how can get the same values?

Tags: java, image, encryption, rgb, rgba

Getting different values of pixels from getRGB after saving image.

Code is as below.

```
public  BufferedImage formImage(List<Integer>  l, int w, int len)
{
    // l = list of zeros and ones

    BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(w, len, 
    BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    dst.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < l.size(); ++k)
    {
        p = 0;
        for (int j = 31; j > -1; --j, ++i)
        {
            p |= (l.get(i) << j); 
        }
        p_out.add(p);
        Color col = new Color(p, true);
        dst.setRGB(k % w, k / w, (new Color(col.getRed(), col.getGreen(), 
        col.getBlue(), col.getAlpha())).getRGB());
        p = dst.getRGB(k % w, k / w);
        //System.out.println("index = " + k + " val = " + p);
    }
    return dst;
}
// in main

BufferedImage test = b.formImage(L2, width, height);

try
{ 

    f1 = new 
    File("E:\\JavaProjects\\BinaryImage\\src\\binaryimage\\out1.bmp");
    if (ImageIO.write(test, "BMP", f1))
    {
        img2 = ImageIO.read(f);
        for (y = 0; y < height; ++y)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < width; ++x)
            {
                L5.add(img2.getRGB(x, y));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i)
        {
            if (L5.get(i) != p_out.get(i))
                System.out.println(L5.get(i) + "!=" + p_out.get(i) + " 
            index = " + i);
        }
    }
}
catch(IOException e) 
{ 
    System.out.println(e); 
}
```

-2631722!=-5329294 index = 0 -3092231!=-2631681 index = 1 -2697567!=-5460897 index = 2 -3158018!=-2697584 index = 3 -3421276!=-5394976 index = 4 -3224018!=-3421372 index = 5 -4408203!=-5131908 index = 6 -3223980!=-4408081 index = 7 -5592397!=-4802928 index = 8 -3289830!=-5592476 index = 9 -5921283!=-4737165 index = 10 -3421185!=-5921335 index = 11 -5658265!=-4605572 index = 12 -3421223!=-5658251 index = 13 -5394994!=-4473949 index = 14

I want to read same values of pixels which I inserted to image.

Comment: What encoding are you saving with?  This is probably caused by JPEG encoding, use PNG.

Comment: I used bmp in above code,but i also used png, jpg and the same problem is found.

Comment: You may test it with simpler numbers and print the results in hexadecimal. You may discover the error. Note: BMP doesn't use alpha, so it may water down the colours. JPEG compress image, so you may lose some details (with hex you may notice if the change is high, or just few bits).

Comment: I used png and this is result                                                                                                     ffd7d7d6!=ffaeae72 index = 0
ffd0d0f9!=ffd7d7ff index = 1
ffd6d6a1!=ffacac5f index = 2
ffcfcffe!=ffd6d690 index = 3
ffcbcba4!=ffadade0 index = 4
ffcece2e!=ffcbcb44 index = 5
ffbcbc75!=ffb1b17c index = 6
ffcece54!=ffbcbcef index = 7
ffaaaab3!=ffb6b690 index = 8
ffcdcd1a!=ffaaaa64 index = 9
ffa5a5fd!=ffb7b773 index = 10
ffcbcbff!=ffa5a5c9 index = 11
ffa9a967!=ffb9b97c index = 12
ffcbcbd9!=ffa9a975 index = 13

Comment: I also used  jpeg and this is result                                                                                     ffd7d7d6!=ffaeae72 index = 0
ffd0d0f9!=ffd7d7ff index = 1
ffd6d6a1!=ffacac5f index = 2
ffcfcffe!=ffd6d690 index = 3
ffcbcba4!=ffadade0 index = 4
ffcece2e!=ffcbcb44 index = 5
ffbcbc75!=ffb1b17c index = 6                                                                                       I need the same pixels to reverse operations to get origin image. I want to encrypt image with key by xoring and reverse operations to get main image.